# Start ViewPager from RecyclerView item

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, android-viewpager, retrofit2

Basically what the title says. I'm trying to start a `ViewPager` activity when a user clicks a `RecyclerView` item. I'm not having problems here, that works fine. The goal is to go from a grid based gallery to viewpager gallery. I'm also trying to send the List<> of data which is loaded over the network. This is where I'm having a lot of trouble. The data is sent through a singleton because it's too large to send through intent and if opened in the new activity too quickly upon app startup, more data is loaded in the original activity (Even if Call is cancelled, using Retrofit2 btw) and I need to notify the adapter, which I have a listener that does.

Another crash that is common is a null pointer when reading an item in viewpager activity, which doesn't make sense to me because the item is not null in the original activity before sending, but if I wait a few seconds it is not null. Some of the code pertaining to my issue can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43647253/pageradapter-changed-adapters-content-with-notifying), a question I asked yesterday with a solution I could not successfully implement.

Please point me in the right direction for starting a ViewPager of the same dataset from a RecyclerView, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are "sending" feed data to the view pager activity, use a shallow copy of the list instead of directly referencing it as shown below

`DataTransferer.get().storeItems(new ArrayList(feed));`

This should prevent `IllegalStateException` raised by feed being updated on your RecyclerView activity.